# pyQt4 import error after updating it to 18.04 LTS

Tags: python, pyqt

I am not able to import `pyqt4` after upgrading my Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04.

I tried re-installing `pyqt4` and python. I also updated `source.list` but nothing worked for me. It was working all good before this update. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt4 import QtGui  # Import the PyQt4 module we'll need
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _ZN15QSessionManager16staticMetaObjectE
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: If my solution below will fail - please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i python | grep -i qt` , `pip list | grep -i qt`, `which python`, `which python3` and `pip3 list | grep -i qt` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you should install one package `python-qt4`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

After installation you will be able to import PyQt4:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.15rc1 (default, Apr 15 2018, 21:51:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>>
```

Comment: I reinstalled my Ubuntu, and everything worked fine.
I know it is not a solution but I tried whatever I could but didn't worked.